# How to get the steps from activity recognition (Combine ActivityRecognitionApi with SensorEventListener)

Tags: android, sensormanager, activity-recognition

I am using Google ActivityRecognitionApi for Android to know when an user is walking, running or cycling.
Is there a way to get the steps that the user executed while practicing each of those activities? I am doing the activity recognition on the background using an IntentService. I need to get the steps also on the background.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to use StepCounter sensor to get these values.

```
public class StepCounterService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Check if the stepCounter is available first.
    List<Sensor> gravSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    for(Sensor each : gravSensors){
    //check for sensor named stepcounter in the list.
            Log.d("Sesnor_list",each.getName());
    }
    //If it's available we can retrieve the value using following code
    Sensor sensor;

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    return START_STICKY;
}
 //An onSensorChanged event gets triggered every time new step count is detected.
  @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event.sensor.getType() == sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER){
        Log.d("step_count = ",event.values[0]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Where should I register the listener? I want to get the steps on the background. I have an IntentService to manage the activity recognised, and every time that a new activity is detected I insert it in the database. I want to insert also the steps detected during the period that the same activity was detected. I already had your solution implemented on the UI, but I don't want to show the real time steps on the UI. Instead I need to use the steps on the background

Comment: I have modified the code, just implement it inside the onstartcommand of the service, It should work fine. Replace line which displays event.values[0] with your call to database.